# REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING: Orchestrator Event: Required event payload key or value missing: stepInstanceId

Tags: visual-workflow, platform-event

An Evaluation Flow is used in my Orchestration to confirm that the step is completed. I have a flow trigger staged on a custom object which stores the orchestrationInstanceId in a custom field.

When the orchestration triggers as me (Admin) it encounters no errors.

When a nonadmin user triggers the same event, an error is reported:

"`Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING: Orchestrator Event: Required event payload key or value missing: stepInstanceId. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.`"

From my understanding, the Orchestration Instance Id value is all that's required to create the platform Event for the orchestration to evaluate itself.

Given it's not asked when a non-admin user triggers it, it appears that there is occurring in the background that needs this and the user doesn't have permission to.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a similar scenario in the past wherein `"REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING: Orchestrator Event: Required event payload key or value missing: stepInstanceId"` exception was thrown when Manage Flows permission is not given. Try giving [Manage Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.retail_task_admin_permission_flow.htm&type=5) permission to fix the error.

This component calls a simple apex method which will publish the orchestration event:

```
public with sharing class DebugOrchestration {
@AuraEnabled
public static void reEvalOrchestration( Id flowInstanceId, Id flowStepInstanceId ) {

Database.SaveResult result = EventBus.publish(
new FlowOrchestrationEvent( OrchestrationInstanceId = flowInstanceId, StepInstanceId = flowStepInstanceId )
);

if ( !result.isSuccess() ) {    
for ( Database.Error err : result.getErrors() ) {   
System.debug( 'The following error has occurred.' );
System.debug( err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() );
System.debug( 'Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields() );
}
throw new AuraHandledException(JSON.serialize( result ) );
}}}
```

StepInstanceId is a required field. It is bypassing for Admin profiles or users with Manage Flows permission.

User with Manage Flow is given elevated access to this event, where they can resume an orchestration even without specifying a step. For a user without this, the field "stepInstanceId" is indeed required.

Hope this helps!